# VBS call Python - sys argument not found

Tags: python, vbscript, command

I have this simple VBScript that calls a Python script:

```vb
Dim value, oShell
value = "someValue"
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
currentCommand = "cmd /k " & Chr(34) & "C:\Temp\test.py" & " " & value & Chr(34)
oShell.Run currentCommand, 1, True
```

Python script looks like this:

```python
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    val = sys.argv[1]
    # continue...
```

The `sys.argv[1]` value comes over fine on my main computer but does not come over on a ToughBook (TB) computer (same software on both).  I get this error on the other computer:

> val = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

If I hard-code the val in the Python code the rest of the Python code works fine on the TB computer.

Does anyone have a thought why this `sys.argv[1]` is not coming over on the other computer?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I copy/pasted your code and it worked just fine. Verify that `cmd` is actually `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: This .exe/path exists on the TB.  Is there a vbs method to verify cmd == C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe?

Comment: First thing to try would be running the command with its full path and extension, and see if the behavior remains the same. Also, are the Python versions identical on both systems?